# TIN-Interpolation always crashing, user error?

Tags: qgis, interpolation, lidar, tools, laz

Perhaps you can help figure this out, maybe i just overlook something.
So i have a point cloud which a imported from a lidar-data-file (laz).
Now, to generate a raster data set, i planned on using the TIN-Interpolation plug-in (well, i guess it is a tool now, not a plug-in).
But any time i open the tool and try to select any parameter, the tool just crashes.

> Stacktrace: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "F:\qgis/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\ui\InterpolationWidgets.py",
> line 117, in addLayer
> self._addLayerData(layer.name(), attribute) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

Do you have any idea on how to work around this issue, how to do it differently or what i might have done wrong?

Comment: The error sounds like no valid layer is passed to some Python function. Are you sure you use the dialog correctly? Maybe you have to explicitly select a layer somewhere?

Comment: @bugmenot123 I observed that the tool crashes not at the very start, but when i try to select the layer (which just happend to always be when i start the dialog). I now suspect the problem to be with my point cloud, i will try to find it.

Comment: I now processed the laz file back and forth and at some point the TIN-Interpolation dialog recognized the layer as valid and it worked just fine. Most likely the problem was with my dataset then. Thanks for the advice.